# Circumvent proxy filter that disables the download of EXE files

Tags: internet, download, proxy

Do you know of a way to download exe files although the web proxy has a filter in place not to allow this?

I have searched for a feature web site that does automatic file renaming. That should certainly make it possible. The solution would take a URL and then change the extension so that it would look to my proxy as I was downloading a .dat file (or similar).

There are perhaps other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding a free website service that has FTP. Sometimes they have software installed that can fetch files from a URL to your webspace and allow you to download them as a zip. Or... Even rename them! Good luck.

P.S. I have a website, and Cpanel has this feature built in I believe.